# Custom View Touch Events

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, touch

I'm trying to implement a custom view in which the user can draw with his finger. Basically, I'm following [this tutorial](http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html).

Everything seems to be working nice, but, given the fact that I also have 2 buttons underneath the custom view like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/mainScreen" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonQuery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/query" />

    <com.example.myapp.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawView"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonSave" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

it actually draws even underneath the buttons and I'm having a hard time understanding why it doesn't capture only the touch events that occur on the DrawView and not outside it. Basically, I can't start the line from above the buttons, but once I start drawing on my view, I can even extend the line outside of it.

As far as I can tell, the DrawView doesn't overflow beneath the buttons, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740252/aligning-controls) so I want to figure out what's going on. Do I really have to check if the events are out of bounds? Does it actually delegate all of the touch events to the currently focused view? Is there any way to change this behavior?

[This simple tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/android_2d_graphics_example,1036/index.html) doesn't have the described issue, but it draws point by point.

---

**Update:** Debugging the application, I determined that drawView has size 480x728, while mainScreen has 480x800, so they do not overlap. It continues to register touch events even if they are triggered outside of the drawView, once it has focus. This is what I'm trying to avoid and it would be nice to do it without passing the event coordinates through a big if statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be some weird bug in the way the Android emulator displays the interface. It may do something similar on real devices (throwing touch events even outside of the listener view), but since it limits the display to the `drawView`, I can safely ignore them for my application, since I just need to extract the drawn shape from the `drawView`. It may cause big headaches in other applications, though...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the buttons to overlap the `DrawView` then use a `LinearLayout` to keep all of the `View`s separate. At the moment, judging from the XML layout (and assuming there isn't anything funky going on with the layout programmatically in code), your buttons *are* overlapping the `DrawView`.

I'm under the impression you're after having the two buttons placed at the top side by side, with the `DrawView` filling the remaining screen area underneath. To do this, use an outer container `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. The first child of it is another `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation, containing the two buttons. The second child of the inner `LinearLayout` is the `DrawView`. Use width, height, and weight attributes to get desired dimensions. (Or, another way is to keep the XML layout structure you have, but set some top margin on the `DrawView` to equal the buttons' height, which could be fixed in the XML layout, or done programmatically.)

**EDIT** Sorry, I totally missed the `layout_above` attribute, which invalidates my second sentence. In that case, without being able to fire up Eclipse at the moment I'm not sure. Try the `LinearLayout` approach as suggested anyway.

Comment: I just debugged it and it does not overlap at all. The drawView has size 480x728, while mainScreen has 480x800. It continues to register touch events even if they are triggered outside of the drawView, once it has focus. This is what I'm trying to avoid and it would be nice to do it without passing the event coordinates through a big `if` statement...

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but how are you determining that it is capturing `MotionEvent`s and drawing *underneath* the buttons? Do your buttons have transparency?

Comment: Actually, it's really weird, because I don't understand on what does it draw. I mean, shouldn't the canvas that is passed to onDraw have the same size as my drawView? I haven't assigned any color to the button, so, by default, they are transparent.

Comment: Indeed, the canvas has size 800, same as mainScreen. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: OK, I found out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954798/why-canvas-is-not-the-same-size-as-view-in-ondraw-android but this still doesn't explain the events issue. I will try to just ignore the events triggered outside the bounds of drawView for now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the differences discussed in that question you linked to are actually due to screen density (see how he mentions a 1.5 factor). It so happens that one of my earliest own SO questions related to this. In your case, I am starting to question how you have determined that `drawView`'s height really is 800px. Where and how did you make the measurement? Try drawing a border on the `canvas` in the `onDraw()` to show where its bounds are, using the following coordinates to draw the rectangle: `0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()` and using a `Paint` with a stroke width of several `px`.

Comment: Relating to the question you linked to, here is my very own question from a while back that seems oddly related to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286483/in-the-ondraw-method-why-does-the-supplied-canvas-already-have-scale. I don't think this is anything to do with your situation, though; if your `drawView` can accept `MotionEvent`s and can visibly draw under those buttons, I can't believe it isn't actually occupying the space beneath them. Hence the suggestion to draw a border, or ensure you're `Log`ging a call to `getHeight()` during the `onDraw()` perhaps.

Comment: Yeah, so basically the canvas that is sent to onPaint has the same size as my #mainScreen, while the #drawView ends above the buttons. I tested this as you suggested, by drawing a rectangle in the onPaint method of my custom view. I don't think it's the same issue as yours and anyway, this is not the biggest issue in my case.

Comment: What was the result of drawing the rectangle border, whose height / width is from `getWidth()` / `getHeight()`? Where did you see the border on the screen? Edit: Ah ok, reading again I think you're saying that the border indicates the `drawView` does `not` overlap the buttons. In that case I'm getting quite stumped!